# Calculate the radius of a circle given a segment's height and area

Tags: geometry

Basically I need to know if there is an non-iterative solution to find the radius of a circle when the segment's area and height are known.

Comment: What segment?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Presumably the OP is asking about a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), in which article formulas may be found to find radius, area, and height related.

Comment: Yes, I was speaking about a circular segment, with H being the height or Rise, having a chord length, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a circle with radius $R$, the area of a segment with height $h\leq R$ is given by
$$ A= R^2 \left(\alpha-\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\right)$$
where $\alpha=\arccos\frac{R-h}{R}$, so in order to find the radius $R$ given $h$ and $A$ we have to solve a trascendental equation similar to Kepler's equation. Newton's method is very well-suited for such a task, but there is no hope for an exact formula.

Comment: I used Newton-Raphson successfully but you of course have to come up with the derivative which is a bit messy though straightforward. I then compared this to the Illinois method which converges much more rapidly than Newton and no need to code up the derivative calculation.